# Is there a way to allow a timer to continue running across multiple screens?

Tags: python, kivy

After changing the code, the error I get is AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**' for the line:

self.get_screen(self.current).ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text = "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)

I would like to know the meaning behind this error so I can fix this problem next time too. Thanks.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, WipeTransition
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import (StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty,
                             ListProperty, DictProperty, BooleanProperty)
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import time
import random
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class SubjectsLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class NavTray1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class BeginScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    number = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.start(), 0.5)

    def increment_time(self, interval):
        self.number += .01
        self.get_screen(self.current).ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text = "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)

    def start(self, dt=0):
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .01)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timer)
        print(f"timer={self.number}")

    def new_page(self):
        name = str(time.time())
        s = Screen1(name=name)
        self.add_widget(s)
        self.current = name

Login = Builder.load_string('''
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
#: import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition


MyScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    BeginScreen:
    Screen1:

<NavTray1>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    padding: '5dp'
    spacing: '5dp'
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgb: .1, .1, .1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Button:
        color: [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1]
        size_hint: (.33, None)
        height: '80dp'
        text: 'Back'
        on_release : app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right')
        on_release : app.root.current = app.root.previous()

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: (.33, 1.0)
        id: custom
        Label:
            id: label_timer

    Button:
        id: submit_button
        color: [6/255, 114/255, 0, 1]
        size_hint: (.33, None)
        height: '80dp'
        text: 'Forward'
        background_color: [28/138, 1, 35/138, 0.5]
        on_release : app.root.new_page()
        on_release : app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left')

<Screen1>:
    name: "start"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        id: box
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: root.height - navtray.height
            SubjectsLayout:
                id: subjects
                cols: 1
                Label:
                    text: root.name
        NavTray1:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            id: navtray
            height: '90dp'

<BeginScreen>:
    name: "begin"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'begin'
            font_size: 50
            pos_hint: {'x':.35, 'y':.45}
            color: [0,1,0,1]

        Button:
            text: 'Lets Begin'
            font_size: 24
            on_press: app.root.new_page()
            size_hint: (.4,.25)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}
            color: [0,0,0,1]

''')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The timer *does* run continuously, but you create a new one with every `Screen1` you instantiate in the `new_page()` call.

Comment: okay, I get that, but how do I link this timer to the other screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 2

> self.get_screen(self.current).ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text =
>   "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)
>
> File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 843, in
>   kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
>
> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

### Root Cause

The Python's Traceback showed the following error before the AttributeError:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 840, in
>   kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
>
> KeyError: 'navtray'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

`self.current` is the name of the screen currently shown, or the screen to show.

When the app runs, the first screen shown is `BigScreen` and in this screen there is no `id` called `navtray`. Due to the missing id: navtray, the app threw *KeyError* first, and then followed by *AttributeError*.

### Solution

There are two solutions to the problem.

#### Method 1

1) In kv file, add a call to method `start()` after call to method `new_page()`

Snippets

```
    Button:
        text: 'Lets Begin'
        font_size: 24
        on_press: app.root.new_page()
        on_press: app.root.start()
```

2) In Python script, remove the constructor, `__init__()` from `class MyScreenManager()` and `dt=0` from method `start()`

Snippets

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    number = NumericProperty(0)

    def increment_time(self, dt):
        self.number += .01
        self.get_screen(self.current).ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text = "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)

    def start(self):
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .01)
```

#### Method 2

Add *if statement* to check `self.current`.

#### Snippets

```
def increment_time(self, interval):
    self.number += .01
    if self.current == 'begin':
        self.get_screen('start').ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text = "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)
    else:
        self.get_screen(self.current).ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text = "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)
```

## Question 1

> Want timer to run continuously through multiple screens

## Solution

- Move class attribute and all methods defined in `class NavTray1` into `class MyScreenManager`
- Update `Label`'s text in `NavTray1` instance from method `increment_time` using `self.get_screen(self.current).ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text = "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)`. We are using `self.current` because as we pressed `Forward` button, we have created new instances of `Screen1` and `NavTray1`.

## Snippets

### kv file

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: (.33, 1.0)
    id: custom
    Label:
        id: label_timer

Button:
    id: submit_button
```

### py file

```
class NavTray1(BoxLayout):
    pass

...
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    number = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.start(), 0.5)

    def increment_time(self, interval):
        self.number += .01
        self.get_screen(self.current).ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text = "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)

    def start(self):
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .01)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timer)
        print(f"timer={self.number}")
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import time


class SubjectsLayout(GridLayout):
    pass


class NavTray1(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    number = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.start(), 0.5)

    def increment_time(self, interval):
        self.number += .01
        self.get_screen(self.current).ids.navtray.ids.label_timer.text = "{0:.2f} secs".format(self.number)

    def start(self):
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .01)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timer)
        print(f"timer={self.number}")


    def new_page(self):
        name = str(time.time())
        s = Screen1(name=name)
        self.add_widget(s)
        self.current = name


Login = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition


MyScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    Screen1:

<NavTray1>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    padding: '5dp'
    spacing: '5dp'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .1, .1, .1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Button:
        color: [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1]
        size_hint: (.33, None)
        height: '80dp'
        text: 'Back'
        on_release : app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right')
        on_release : app.root.current = app.root.previous()


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: (.33, 1.0)
        id: custom
        Label:
            id: label_timer

    Button:
        id: submit_button
        color: [6/255, 114/255, 0, 1]
        size_hint: (.33, None)
        height: '80dp'
        text: 'Forward'
        background_color: [28/138, 1, 35/138, 0.5]
        on_release : app.root.new_page()
        on_release : app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left')

<Screen1>:
    name: "start"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        id: box
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: root.height - navtray.height
            SubjectsLayout:
                id: subjects
                cols: 1
                Label:
                    text: root.name
        NavTray1:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            id: navtray
            height: '90dp'
```

## Output

[image: Kivy ScreenManager - Timer runs continuously across multiple screens]

Comment: Hi Ikolim, I updated the code, but somehow I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Please check updated post for the root cause and solution.

Comment: Thanks so much once again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add a *new* timer with every new page you create.
One way to keep the same timer, is to take the first `NavTray1` and use it in the next page.
To achieve this, you have to change your `new_page` method like this:

```
def new_page(self):
    box = self.current_screen.ids["box"]
    navtray = box.children[0]  # get the original Navtray1 here
    box.remove_widget(navtray)

    name = str(time.time())
    s = Screen1(name=name)

    new_box = s.ids["box"]
    new_box.remove_widget(new_box.children[0])  # remove the current NavTray1
    new_box.add_widget(navtray)  # add the original Navtray1 here

    self.add_widget(s)
    self.current = name
```

You could do it in a better way by keeping a reference to the `NavTray1` but that needs some changes to your `kv` file and I wanted to avoid a code re-write..